# CURLOPT_POST Fields Empty

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following code to POST.  However, the contents of $_POST are null.  What am I missing here?

```
$orderData = "This is an order";
$json = json_encode($orderData);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:9999/printpost.php",
  CURLOPT_CAINFO => "C:\MAMP\conf\php7.0.0\cacert.pem",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: ".$oauthToken,
    "content-type: application/json",
    "programid: ".$programId
  ),
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the fields of `$_POST` to be? You haven't specified a name for the post field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$_POST` superglobal is only used for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; i.e. key/value pairs formatted like `foo=1&bar=2`. You're posting JSON. Consume it like this on the server side instead of using the superglobal:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Additionally, I recommend the following changes in the cURL client code you posted:

Replace

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
```

with

```
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
```

And add

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

The POST data should not be encoded as JSON, it should be a URL-encoded string in the form `name=value&name=value&...`. Furthermore, even if JSON were processed, you didn't specify a name for your parameter, so what were you expecting the key in `$_POST` to be?

If you provide an associative array as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it will automatically encode it for you.

```
'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => array('orderData' => $orderData)
```

Then in the server script you can use `$_POST['orderData']`